# reading response url and its query parameter in postman

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

I have to call an API which redirects to a new URL with response in URL parameters. I want to capture these response URL and its parameters in postman.

Say I call https://endpoint.com/xyz it redirects to https://endpoint.com/redirect?flag=true
I want to capture flag value.

Can it be done in postman script? How can I do it in Postman Script?

Comment: Is this 301 redirect? if not, what is the status code you receives?

Comment: First it is a 302 redirect then the response status is 200. In the response URL I want read the flag parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the postman settings, you need to disable `Automatically follow redirects`.

Then, you need to get the response header of the request that returns the 302.
You can then get the flag via a regex (or other string operation, if you prefer)

```
let location = postman.getResponseHeader("Location")

let flag = location.match(/flag=(.*)(&|$)/)[1];
```

Comment: In postman I had to escape the `&` such as `(.*)(\&|$)` for it to work. I ended up using the negate set, a favorite of mine, instead for `match(/code=([^&]+)(\&|$)/)[1];`